# How do you get the Scanner to pause for input when running the program again?

Tags: java, user-input

So as a little challenge to myself to test what I have learned of Java so far, I decided to make a program to apply the writing quirk of a character from a webcomic(Sol Captor from Heartstuck, for those curious) to the user's input using a switch statement. So far, the program works fine and the quirk is applied fine, but, when I went to make the program ask the user if they want to run the program again, when then said yes, the program would run again, except it didn't pause to allow the user to type another statement to have the quirk applied to. I have tried putting all the declarations, except char restart, inside the while loop and adding the line "sol.Next();" after "System.out.println("Normal");." Neither of these have worked and I cannot find any information anywhere on how to fix this. Here is my code for reference:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SolQuirk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char restart = 'y';
        Scanner sol = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("");
        String input = "";
        while(restart == 'y' | restart == 'n'){
            System.out.println("Normal:");
            while(!sol.hasNext("\n")){
                char ch = sol.next().charAt(0);
                switch(ch){
                    case 's': case 'S':
                        input += '2';
                        break;
                    case ' ':
                        input += ch;
                        ch = sol.next().charAt(0);
                        if(ch == 't' || ch == 'T'){
                            ch = sol.next().charAt(0);
                            if(ch == 'o' || ch == 'O'){
                                ch = sol.next().charAt(0);
                                if(ch == 'o' || ch == 'O'){
                                    ch = sol.next().charAt(0);
                                    if(ch == ' ' || ch == '.'){
                                        input += "two";
                                        input += ch;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        input += "too";
                                        input += ch;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                else if(ch == ' ' || ch == '.'){
                                    input += "two";
                                    input += ch;
                                    break;
                                }
                                else{
                                    input += "to";
                                    input += ch;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                input += "t";
                                input += ch;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    default:
                        input += ch;
                        break;
                }
            }
            String solQuirk = input.toLowerCase();
            System.out.println("Sol:");
            System.out.println(solQuirk);
            System.out.println("Would you like to go again? y/n");
            try {
                restart = (char) System.in.read();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SolQuirk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Most beautiful indentation, I have ever seen!

Comment: How are you editing and compiling your code? If you are using an IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse, you should use the debugger to step through your code to find out what is happening. Alternatively, you can add `System.out.println()` calls to your code in order to trace through the execution and view values of variables.

Comment: @DekDekku Give the OP a break! At least the code *is* formatted, unlike 90% of the questions around here.

Comment: But I love it. It's basically a Finite State Machine. Kind of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think mixing `System.in.read` with a `Scanner` is a good idea. It seems to be causing some kind of problem with who is consuming the characters being inputted.

Said that, replacing this part of your code

```
try {
     restart = (char) System.in.read();
} catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(SolQuirk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

with

```
// remove the last \n 
sol.nextLine();
// get the user response and consume the whole line
restart = sol.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Solves the problem.

I'm not enterily sure where the error on your code is, but it haves to do with a `\n` not being consumed, thus not entering on your quirky loop.